# Post photo to facebook page as page

Tags: php, api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I need to post a photo in a facebook page as page instead of myself.This is my code:

```
function postFeedBack(userID) {
    FB.api('/page_id/photos', 'post', {
      access_token : FB.getAuthResponse()['accessToken'],
      message: "message",
            url   : 'image_url',
      from : page_id
    }, function (response) {
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured');
        } else {
            alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
```

I need to post a photo in facebook page as posted by page name, instead of username. Am using the permissions 'publish_stream, manage_pages'.

Thanks,
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that the oauth user will need manage_pages permission, too.

Update:

Please see [developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos) - also, just to be sure, you are replacing "page_id" with the id of your page, right? Also, double check that the access token is issued to a user who is a Page Manager for said page. In addition, double-check the parameters you're sending. I could be wrong and/or the documentation may be out of date but **I do not see "url" as a valid parameter to POST /PAGE_ID/photos**. Facebook appears to want image data here in the source parameter. See FB docs link.

Comment: I have tried using manage_pages permissions but doesn't work.I need to post a photo to my facebook page posted as page,actually is it possible?not as feed but as photos ie my issue..When i try to post the photo it is working but the post is appearing like user posted a photo..  how can i solve this?